# How to show holidays and Weekdays(weekends which are not holyday included) via excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Info:My current version of excel is 2016.**

Hi currently ive a table that shows the  days of the week(mon-sun) based on the day of the week but holydays wasnt included so i tried the next formula(ive also a holyday table which search the HOlydays dates):

```
=IF(WORKDAY($J$5-1;1;HOLYDAY!$A$2:$A$673)=$J$5;$J$5;"HOL")
```

Now its also showing the Weekends as Holydays on my table
like this:

Mond - Tues - Wedn - Thur - Frid - HOL - HOL - Mond - Tues- HOL(pretend  Wedn is a holyday which is correct)and so goes on.

But i was expecting for that result instead:

Mond - Tues - Wedn - Thur - Frid - Satu- Sund - Mond - Tues- HOL

**PS:If u need any more info to help me let me know**

Comment: Have you considered networkdays.intl ?

Comment: Yes i did, networkdays returns the same result and networkdays.intl returns a number. Might have not done it in the proper way since im expecting to return the day of the week. i Could post the test results if u want.

Comment: @SolarMike Do you have anything in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all days (including weekend days) need to be converted to "Mond" etc., except when they are included in a list of self-declared "Holydays" (holidays), then you don't need `WORKDAY()` (or `NETWORKDAYS()` for that matter). You can just check if a cell has a match in your holiday range. If so, return "HOL", else return "Mond" etc.

Not exactly sure how to imagine your table, but something like the following should work:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(J5;HOLYDAY!$A$2:$A$673;0);"HOL");LEFT(TEXT(J5;"DDDD");4))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly. Do u mind adding a quick explanation about the formula? im quite new to excel.

Comment: i know how most formulas u have used works just not sure about the last part 'LEFT(TEXT(J5;"DDDD");4))' and also i didnt knew that u could use Match for Dates. Thank you for the knowledge.

Comment: In Excel, dates are numbers, with 1 = `1/1/1900` etc. If you enter a date in a cell, Excel automatically *formats* it as a date, but it will still just be a number underneath. `TEXT(value;"format code")` allows you to set a specific format for dates (and all sorts of value types). See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c). `TEXT(J5;"DDDD")` leads to day in full, like "Monday". You seemed interested in just the first 4 letters, hence the `LEFT(...;4)` wrapper ("DDD" would have gotten you "Mon", a more common abbreviation).

Comment: Thanks! ive been learning excel and VBA for about a week and im loving it(still noob) but the amount of possibilities is overwhelming!